# Questions regarding Set as Ringtone Android

Tags: android, listview, ringtone

1st. I got a code to set as Ringtone. One thing I don't understand. I have 64 sound files in my application. Is there a way to get something like ID when I click on some button or I have to write whole code for all 64 files?

2nd. I have a listview in my app, and I want on long item click to set that file as ringtone.
Now. Do I need to write whole code into case, or I can make another activity and then just set ringtone using that way? Something like this

```
case 1:
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
          myActivity,
          Activity name.TYPE_RINGTONE,
          newUri
break;
```

Well that's about it,  Is it possible to get ID from file, copy that file and set it as ringtone on long click, or I need to write code for all 64 files? 
Edit: If 1st question is not possible, how should I write code for all 64 files? Where to put them? And how can I define which file to be copied when I click on certain button. Or list view

My code is:

```
l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String selectedName = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1)).getContext().toString();

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                }

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyRingtones/Audio/";

                File out = new File(path + "/", selectedName);     
                if(!out.exists()){
                    copyFile(assetManager, "Yeah.mp3", out);
                }           

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, out.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "yeah");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, out.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(out.getAbsolutePath());
                ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
                Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

                try {
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                             getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                    Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,
                            newUri.toString());
                } 
                catch (Throwable t) 
                {
                    //TODO Handle exception
                }
                switch (position){
                case 0:
                     if(mp!=null)
                        {
                            mp.release();
                            mp=null;
                        }

                     MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.aint);
                        mp.start();
                    break;
                case 1:
                     if(mp!=null)
                        {
                            mp.release();
                            mp=null;
                        }

                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                                R.raw.airh);
                        mp.start();
```

LOGCAT:

```
02-25 09:21:34.064: W/dalvikvm(10221): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41aac8b0)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at funnysounds.com.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:63)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1104)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2792)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3468)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-25 09:21:34.074: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you try with `onItemClick()` method ?

Comment: Yeah, and it didn't work.
I can't figure how to set to create file and set that created file as ringtone on 1 click. I can't make it work onItemClick() in list view. I am  new in android development. I made test app, added  1 button and it worked.So I was wondering if there is some way something like: On item click>Execute Activity>But not to change layout.

Comment: Ok one question first, should I put whole code in case? Or just some parts.
I pasted whole code in case and it gave me so many syntax errors that did't even make sense. Mostly to replace ; with , and similar. I did that and code was well never used

Comment: Ok, in order to use `case x: {...} break;` you have to surround it with `switch TheValueYouWantToCheck{case 0:{...}break;default: break;` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I got it to work but application crashes when I click on any Item.
I updated code above with logcat.

Comment: Sorry I edited again.

Comment: Ok, the error seems to be at `MainActivity.java:63` so what's your 63rd line ?

Comment: `String selectedName = ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1)).getContext().toString();
`
I am using default list view from android resources. Listview widget and style simple_list_view_1 from android resources. Since I didn't have any text view to edit I replaced it with list view.


`l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sounds);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48342/discussion-between-samoth-and-sabroan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a switch but put a click listener :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            // selected item
           String selectedName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textView_item_id)).getText().toString();

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyRingtones/Audio/";

            File out = new File(path + "/", selectedName);     
            if(!out.exists()){
                try {
                    copyFile(assetManager, "Yeah.mp3", out);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, out.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "yeah");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, out.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(out.getAbsolutePath());
            ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
            Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

            try {
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,
                        newUri.toString());
            } 
            catch (Throwable t) 
            {
                //TODO Handle exception
            }

        }
      });
```

Comment: I get this weird error, Syntax Error on "case" token, assert expected.
Syntax Error on token ":", ";" expected.
And

The method setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Context, int, Uri) in the type RingtoneManager is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, 
 int, Uri)

Comment: I edited code.
I am using list view style from android resources, simple_list_item_1